# Поиск слова в строке Amino

Tags: python, бот

Есть код, который реагирует на определенное слово и кикает с чата.
Но оно реагирует сугубо если слово в тексте лишь одно, то есть если будет несколько слов в тексте, то оно не реагирует. Как переписать правильно, чтобы он проходился по всему тексту и искал в нем определенное слово

```
    if (data.message.type == 100) | (data.message.type == 109) | 
    (data.message.type == 107)  | (data.message.type == 110) | 
    (data.message.type == 108)  | (data.message.type == 111) | 
    (data.message.type == 0)
     and (data.message.content == "KKK" ) | 
    (data.message.content == "Lala") | (data.message.content == "Привет от мрака"):
sub_client.send_message(message=(f'Рейдер {nickname} был кикнут из чата навсегда.'), chatId=data.message.chatId)
                    sub_client.kick(userId=data.message.author.userId, chatId=data.message.chatId, allowRejoin = False)
                    nom = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наличие любого слова из списка можно проверить так. Я ещё сделал приведение проверяемого текста и слов к одному регистру:

```
stop_words = ['привет', 'пока', 'хзчтотакое']

if any(word.lower() in data.message.content.lower() for word in stop_words):
    ...
```

А ещё вы зря мешаете **логические операторы** `and` и `or` с **побитовыми операторами** `|` и `&`, лучше так не делать. В данном случае используйте логические операторы. И скобки расставьте, а то результат проверок, думаю, будет не совсем такой, как вы ожидаете. Да, и другую проверку тоже можно сократить, используя проверку вхождения элемента в список `in`. В целом будет так примерно:

```
stop_words = ["KKK", "Lala", "Привет от мрака"]

if data.message.type in [0, 100, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111] and
   any(word.lower() in data.message.content.lower() for word in stop_words):
    ...
```

Comment: File "/Users/aleks/amino-bot/mainBot.py", line 165, in <module>
    if any(word.lower() in data.message.content.lower() for word in stop_words):
NameError: name 'stop_words' is not defined

Что я не сделал не так?

Comment: Ну я выше привёл пример что там должно быть. Добавил во второй кусок кода вариант с вашими данными.

Comment: Хорошо, большое спасибо, вроде бы разобрался с документацией.  А не подскажите еще, пожалуйста. Как написать самый простой счетчик против спама? То есть если в секунду прилетает 5,10,15 смс от одного человека.

Comment: @АлексейКожевников Это совсем другой вопрос, задайте его лучше отдельно

Comment: Да, задайте лучше отдельно, я сделал счетяючик, но лучше я покажу решение отдельно

Comment: Тогда жду в новом вопросе :3

Answer (score 1):

`if "слово" in "текст"` или `if "текст".find("слово") != -1`

Comment: А как тогда считать данные, которые вводят люди?

Comment: всмысле? как это мешает

Comment: Прошу прощения, разобрался. А как добавить несколько слов для реагирования? if "текст".find("слово","слово") != -1 
Или как-то иначе? Я новичок в этом